# javascript click the flash/swf button on page

Tags: java, javascript, flash, firefox, imacros

I am working on iMacros script (iMacros is addon for FireFox and it supports JS).

I want to write a JavaScript code which will click swf button and open it to read image file from Hard Drive and upload it to web form.

This the HTML code of the form

```
<ul id="plupload-container_post-ad_image-select" class="image-container-droppable">
<li id="image-upload-trigger-container" style="visibility: visible;">
<a id="plupload-select_post-ad_image-select" class="secondary button" href="#">Add image</a>
<div id="p17fn085741qvovjsbhpcse1ff90_flash_container" class="plupload flash" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; z-index: 99999; width: 90px; height: 27px; left: 0px; cursor: pointer;">
<object id="p17fn085741qvovjsbhpcse1ff90_flash" width="100%" height="100%" style="outline:0" data="/common/plupload/plupload.flash.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param value="/common/plupload/plupload.flash.swf" name="movie">
<param value="id=p17fn085741qvovjsbhpcse1ff90" name="flashvars">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
</object>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

In FireBug I see that there is a function that might trigger the uploading.

http://prntscr.com/no5fl

And here goes the code of function if it's necessary. http://pastebin.com/y48XzakJ

When I want to execute javascript code in iMacros I do it like this.

```
URL GOTO=javascript:some_javascript_command_written_in_one_line_of_code
```

What this does it pastes everything after URL GOTO=   into navigation bar.

So I need the function which will help me and that I can execute it in iMacros in the way I just described it. Is this possible or do I have to explain more?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to click on flash object with imacros is by DS command which does not work in Firefox add-on

Comment: Well then you are wrong since it's possible to click it by calling javascript event which does that normally on the page.

Comment: in this case I would also like to see it

Comment: I found a solution. Disabling JavaScript make the Browse button pop out and path bar is visible. So it's possible to record macro for this option. No need for javascript code.

Comment: yes, I know this workaround, but it will work only on websies which have simple version of flash uploader.

Comment: Good enough. Until I find a javascript solution that will have to work.